# Is living area very different from residential area?

Tags: word-meaning

I had been living in a big city in Australia for a few years before I moved to other countries in Asia.

Out of curiosity, someone asked me in Whatsapp why I often went to some particular library in Monash.

> "because it was close to my living area...", I said.

Some of them laughed in the whatsapp group, but I did not get it then, I thought they were laughing because of something else.
(I captured some screenshot)

But now I thought it might be the word, living area, so I posted this question.

I should have written residential area, not living area, am I right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatic ways to answer the question:

> I go that library because it's near where I live.
>
> I visit that library because it's close to my house|apartment|flat.
>
> I go to that library because it's not far from where I  live.
>
> I go to that library because it's in my neighborhood.
>
> I go to that library because it's nearby.
>
> I go to that library because it's not far from me.
>
> I go to that library because it's convenient.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**
*I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure about the validity and the extend of usage of the following term, but this may be the reason why they laughed.*

In my country (India), the biggest room of a house, mostly the common room, or the main hall, is often referred to as living area, or **[Living room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_room)**. Where as, as you said, the locality near your house should be addressed as '*residential area*' or simply, your '*residential locality*'. But this can be ambiguous.

A residential area need not mean the area surrounding your residence.

> A residential area is a land use in which housing predominates, as opposed to industrial and commercial areas. Housing may vary significantly between, and through, residential areas. These include single-family housing, multi-family residential, or mobile homes. -**[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residential_area)**

So, if you wanted to talk about a library near your home, you could say:

> "because it was close to my residence"

rather than to say '*residential area*'. Or if you meant that the library is near the collective area of a number of residences, then *'residential area'* is perfectly fine.